# Server returned HTTP response code: 415 for URL (java/xml)

Tags: java, xml, odata

I have a problem with my connect to url (xml) file, and create java objects. So far I can't connect to my link due to "Server returned HTTP response code: 415 for URL"

My link: http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Employees

My code (not complete, but the exception is thrown there):

```
 package logic;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XMLReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
        //JsonObject requestJson = new JsonObject();
        String url = "http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Employees";
        URL myurl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)myurl.openConnection();
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setDoInput(true);

        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml; charset=utf-8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
        con.setRequestProperty("Method", "GET");

        InputStream xml = con.getInputStream();

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(xml);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

make 
con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml"); 
to 
con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/xml");

Comment: still response  415?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I changed "application/xml" to "text/xml" and it worked.